# Android Retrofit by lazy API - Response with last one hour data

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit by lazy API.

The json data received and all okay. Only problem is the next retrieve is from cache...
only 1 hour later get new data.

How can i resolve this problem.

```
val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(6, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(6, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(6, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
    .build()
    OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()

    private val retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    val api: SimpleApi by lazy {
        retrofit.create(SimpleApi::class.java)
    }
```

}

class CacheInterceptor : Interceptor {
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

```
    val request = chain.request()
    val originalResponse = chain.proceed(request)
    val CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER = "Cache-Control"
    val CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_VALUE = "public, max-age=60"

    val CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE = "no-cache"

    val shouldUseCache = request.header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER) != CACHE_CONTROL_NO_CACHE

    if (!shouldUseCache) return originalResponse

    val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
            .maxAge(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .noCache()
            .build()

        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .removeHeader(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER)
            .header(CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER, CACHE_CONTROL_HEADER_VALUE )
            .build()
        Log.d("sync-john", "----> sync cache cache control")


}
```

Comment: Did you try removing `CacheInterceptor` entirely? By default there will be no cache at all so if your response is still not the latest, it will be a caching problem from the server. You can try adding `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to see if the response come from API or not

Comment: Remove all of this " .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())"?

Comment: Yep, If you don't want to handle caching locally, then usually you don't need this logic

Comment: Remove " .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor()) " still doesn't work ...

Comment: How about logging API response with `HttpLoggingInterceptor`? If the cache last for 1 hour I assume it is caching logic from the server

Comment: How to modify the source code to include HttpLoggingInterceptor. my source code is from tutorial ...is working .but.. no matter how many sync is press ...only get latest after 1 hour. then another 1 hour to have new records again.

Comment: val intercepter = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }
    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        this.addInterceptor(intercepter)
            // time out setting
            .connectTimeout(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(25,TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    }.build()

Comment: i add in above ? how to check n logcat ?

Comment: Open Logcat window on your Android Studio, it's where every log is printed

Comment: Have check the log filter by OkHttp.... showing is from the previous cache... until 1 hour later will give new ...

Comment: Then check with your API provider, backend team. It's definitely caching from API and the client app cannot do anything about it.

Comment: The API Provider is just a simple web rest api developed by me.  When testing using POSTMAN / WEB BROWSER is always display latest info. But Android App only display latest once then need to wait for 1 hour to have the latest Info again.

Comment: I still keep my point because I've worked with `Retrofit` for a quite long time, and they don't do any caching by default. If you want to cache, you have to manually do that by using `Interceptor` or `OkHttp` cache method. `Retrofit` always gives you a new request and returns whatever response the server gives. Besides, `by lazy` is not the cause here because you have to keep the `Retrofit` instance anyway, it is just a wrapper for you to call the API and doesn't do any caching

Comment: If you want to test if `Retrofit` actually calls your API or using cache response, debug or log your server to check if any incoming request go into the backend when request API from the app

Comment: i will check  if any incoming request go into the backend when request API from the app from the debug or log.

Answer (score 0):

**Key Points about lazy**

-lazy is applicable to both mutable (var) and read-only (val) properties.

-The lazy delegate is thread-safe by default, ensuring that the initialization code is executed only once, even in a concurrent environment.

-The lazy delegate is calculated at the point of the first access and cached thereafter.

I do some reading on Retrofit by lazy.... as in third point (cached thereafter). May be can't use by lazy else will be cached, is it what it meant ?

Comment: `Retrofit` doesn't cache any response data without any further configuration about caching. The logic of "cached thereafter" in `by lazy` means cache the instance of `Retrofit` inside the variable for further usage without recreating it everytime. So `by lazy` has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Ok will find out more how to fix this

Comment: This is the Logcat :-

Comment: ... D/OkHttp: --> GET https://dhnkk.com/restserver/apkclients.php?sm=20
... D/OkHttp: --> END GET
... D/OkHttp: <-- 200 https://dhnkk.com/restserver/apktrans.php?sm=20 (957ms) 
... D/OkHttp: date: Fri, 12 Jan 2024 07:38:21 GMT
... D/OkHttp: server: nginx/1.21.6...
... D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json
2024-01-12 15:38:23.239 21174-21792/com.uc D/OkHttp: vary: Accept-Encoding
2024-01-12 15:38:23.239 21174-21792/com.uc D/OkHttp: x-server-cache: true
2024-01-12 15:38:23.239 21174-21792/com.uc D/OkHttp: x-proxy-cache: HIT

Comment: In the logcat mention 1.  x-server-cache: true

Comment: 2. x-proxy-cache: HIT

Comment: Not sure what does it mean ?

Comment: Yup the headers say something about the cache is hit, so the response is from cache, not from server. Research about your nginx server configuration about this